# Three.js not loading mtl file with map_ks -s and bump -s instructions

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the following mtl file:

```
newmtl blinn_backSG
illum 4
Kd 0.17 0.15 0.28
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
bump -s 0.1 0.1 canvas_specular.tif -bm 0.025
Ni 1.00
Ks 0.00 0.00 0.00
map_Ks -s 0.1 0.1 canvas_specular.tif
newmtl blinn_boxSG
illum 4
Kd 0.00 0.00 0.00
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
map_Kd -s 0.333333 0.333333 canvas_map.tif
bump -s 0.333333 0.333333 canvas_map.tif -bm 0.1
Ni 1.00
Ks 0.00 0.00 0.00
map_Ks -s 0.333333 0.333333 -mm 0 0.503822 canvas_specular.tif
newmtl blinn_hungerSG
illum 4
Kd 0.00 0.00 0.00
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ni 1.00
Ks 1.00 1.00 1.00
newmtl initialShadingGroup
illum 4
Kd 0.50 0.50 0.50
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ni 1.00
```

Notice the `bump -s` and `map_Ks -s` instructions. Those instructions do not appear to be being interpreted correctly via that MTLLoader-- i see the following errors in my chrome devtools console:

```
three.js:18393 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/objs/canvas-test/-s%200.1%200.1%20canvas_specular.tif%20-bm%200.025 404 (File not found)load @ three.js:18393load @ three.js:18507load @ three.js:20043loadTexture @ MTLLoader.js:468createMaterial_ @ MTLLoader.js:437create @ MTLLoader.js:329preload @ MTLLoader.js:297(anonymous function) @ previews.html:178(anonymous function) @ MTLLoader.js:36(anonymous function) @ three.js:18347
2016-07-08 08:30:45.396 three.js:18393 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/objs/canvas-test/-s%200.333333%200.333333%20canvas_map.tif 404 (File not found)load @ three.js:18393load @ three.js:18507load @ three.js:20043loadTexture @ MTLLoader.js:468createMaterial_ @ MTLLoader.js:393create @ MTLLoader.js:329preload @ MTLLoader.js:297(anonymous function) @ previews.html:178(anonymous function) @ MTLLoader.js:36(anonymous function) @ three.js:18347
2016-07-08 08:30:45.397 three.js:18393 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/objs/canvas-test/-s%200.333333%200.333333%20canvas_map.tif%20-bm%200.1 404
```

See how its trying to use the flag and positioning arguments as part of the URL?

Does the MTLObjectLoader support this style of instruction? If not, is there a way for me to fix/change the mtl in order to make it use a different instruction?

Thanks--

Comment: Not all MTL values are supported in THREE.js, you can use JSON as alternative. But Json can't smooth shading.

Comment: @Martin if the json one you're talking about is the output of the nodejs objtojson npm package, that one def doesnt support what i'm looking for either

Comment: Three.js' ASCII JSON format. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender

Answer (score 0):

This stripped down example shows a typical MTL file I use with OBJLoader.js and MTLLoader.js:

```
# Blender MTL File: 'INC1c_1.blend'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Inc1cMiscTexture
Ns 100
Kd .6 .6 .6
Ks 0.02 0.02 0.02
d 1.000000
illum 1
map_kd textures/Inc1cMisc_CO.png
map_bump textures/Inc1cMisc_NO.png
```

Whatever I get out of the modeling program is fixed up to fit this pattern. r69 to r78. FWIW

Edit - according to the release summary, r79 just added support for map_Ks in MTLLoader.